# Calculate the real part , imaginary part , module , conjugate and the inverse of this complex number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have this number $ $  $  2e^{-2\pi i/3}$.

What theory I have to apply to resolve it? I done with an easy number like this one:

$z=(1+ i)^{3}$

$-z = (-1 -i)^{3}$

$\overline{z} = (1 -i)^{3}$

$|Z| = {\sqrt1^2 + 1^2} = {\sqrt2^3} = {\sqrt8}$

I'm not sure if the solution of the second one is well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$. your number is $Z=2e^{-2\pi i/3}$ so
$$
\begin{align}
Z&=2\cdot e^{-2\pi i/3} 
\\
\\
&= 2\cdot\Big(\cos(-2\pi/3)+i\sin(-2\pi/3)\Big)\\ \\
&= 2\cdot\Big(-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \Big)\\ \\
&= -1 - i\sqrt{3}\\ \\
&= -(1 + i\sqrt{3})
\end{align}
$$
and
$|Z|= 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $e^{xi} = \cos x + i\sin x$. With this in mind, calculate the value using $x = \frac{-2\pi}{3}$

Comment: Then the result is calculate cos −2π/3 + i sin −2π/3?

Comment: You want to know the real and imaginary components of $2e^{\frac{-2\pi i}{3}}$. Use that rule and the rules of trigonometry to calculate the value. This trigonometry [unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle#/media/File:Unit_circle_angles_color.svg) might be helpful for your calculations.